# How can I diff a Postgres table against a sqlserver table

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

We are in the process of migrating from `sql server 2008R2` to `postgres v14`.

We have created the appropriate tables and populated them and have our apps writing to both databases.

What is the best way to diff tables on both databases to ensure that we are properly writing to both database's properly.

We can assume sql server is correct as this is our current production database.

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are identical it is easiest to compare using the foreign data wrapper for mssql. Doing so gives you access to both at the same time, looking from the Postgres side.